# Construct date for specific day of current month and convert it to epoch

Tags: date, converters, epoch

I need epoch of 4th day of current month.

I have this:

```
START_DT=$(date +"%Y-%m-04 00:00:00")
START_DT_TS=$(date -d "$START_DT" +%s)
```

Output is 1433368800 which is expected.

How I achieve this on single line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try backqoutes approach

```
date -d "`date +\"%Y-%m-04 00:00:00\"`" +%s
```